# Javascript : Automatically get if else function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to get the number of days a person worked according to his `in-time` and `out-time`. And it should automatically calculate on day field when it's selected from the table row and it's not working with my js code

**HTML**

```
<fieldset> In-Time:
   <input class="input" type="text" name="InTime" id="intime" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>Out-Time:
    <input class="input" type="text" name="OutTime" id="outtime" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset> Day:
   <input class="input" type="text" id="day" name="Day" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#intime').on('input', function() {
    if (intime == 08:00:00 && outtime >= 18:00:00) {
      day == 1;
    }else if (intime == 08:00:00 && outtime == 12:30:00) {
      day == 0.5;
    }else (intime == 12:30:00 && outtime >= 18:00:00) {
      day == 0.5;
    };
  });
  $('#outtime').on('input', function() {
    if (intime == 08:00:00 && outtime >= 18:00:00) {
      day == 1;
    }else if (intime == 08:00:00 && outtime == 12:30:00) {
      day == 0.5;
    }else (intime == 12:30:00 && outtime >= 18:00:00) {
      day == 0.5;
    };
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Have you declared intime  and outtime  variables?

Comment: You have to convert your times to a timestamp, with something like `strtotime()`.

Comment: undefined variables. Your console should have spotted the error

Comment: no it works for other fields except for if statement

Comment: it worked. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment.js to parse time.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#intime,#outtime').on('input', function() {
        // declare variables
        var intime = new moment($("#intime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); // get value of intime
        var outtime= new moment($("#outtime").val(), 'HH:mm:ss'); 
        
        var startTime = new moment("08:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss');
        var halfDay = new moment("12:30:00", 'HH:mm:ss');
        var wholeDay = new moment("18:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss');
                
        
        var day = 0; // declare day as 0
         if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && moment(outtime).hour() >= 18) {
            day = 1;
        }
        else if (moment(intime).hour() == 8 && (moment(outtime).hour() == 12 && moment(outtime).minute() == 30)) {
   day = 0.5;
  }
     else if ((moment(intime).hour() == 12 && moment(intime).minute() == 30) && moment(outtime).hour() >= moment(wholeDay).hour()) {
            day = 0.5;
        }
      $("#day").val(day);
      /*console.log("imtime", moment(intime).hour());
      console.log("intime", moment(intime).minute());
      console.log("outtime",moment(outtime).hour());
      console.log("outtime",moment(outtime).minute());
      console.log("wholeDay", moment(wholeDay).hour());*/
      
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<fieldset> In-Time:
   <input class="input" type="text" name="InTime" id="intime" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>Out-Time:
    <input class="input" type="text" name="OutTime" id="outtime" value="" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset> Day:
   <input class="input" type="text" id="day" name="Day" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your script as below:-

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#intime,#outtime').on('input', function() {
        // declare variables
        var intime = $("#intime").val() || 0;; // get value of intime
        var outtime= $("#outtime").val() || 0;; // get value of outtime
        var day = 0; // declare day as 0
        if (intime == 08:00:00 && outtime >= 18:00:00) {
            day == 1;
        }else if (intime == 08:00:00 && outtime == 12:30:00) {
            day == 0.5;
        }else (intime == 12:30:00 && outtime >= 18:00:00) {
            day == 0.5;
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of intime and outtime. and check the syntax errors in your code there are multiple.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#intime').on('input', function() {
        var intime = $("#intime").val();
        var outtime= $("#outtime").val();
        if (intime == '08:00:00' && outtime >= '18:00:00') {
            day == 1;
        }else if (intime == '08:00:00' && outtime == '12:30:00') {
            day == 0.5;
        }else if(intime == '12:30:00' && outtime >= '18:00:00') {
            day == 0.5;
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function (){
      $('#outtime').on('input', function() {
        var intime = $("#intime").val();
        var outtime= $("#outtime").val();
        if (intime == '08:00:00' && outtime >= '18:00:00') {
            day == 1;
        }else if (intime == '08:00:00' && outtime == '12:30:00') {
            day == 0.5;
        }else if(intime == '12:30:00' && outtime >= '18:00:00') {
            day == 0.5;
        }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```